# How can I convert multiple row of data to single row in pd dataframe by column name base on its value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the data as below it will contain the categories and data with multiple row,

```
key date    cat1    cat2    id1 data1   data2   data3   data4   id2 data5   data5   data6   data7   id3 data8   data9   data10  id4 data11  data12  data13
x   0       7       foo     54  4065    -41     -78     102     0   126     16      119     60522   na  na      na      na      na  na      na      na
x   0       7       foo     53  4200    -42     -87     102     0   130     12      119     na      na  na      na      na      na  na      na      na
x   0       7       foo     60  4203    -46     -114    102     0   130     12      118     na      na  na      na      na      na  na      na      na
x   0       7       foo     61  na      na      na      na      1   na      na      na      na      1   15000   57      5481    na  na      na      na
x   0       7       foo     54  na      na      na      na      1   na      na      na      na      4   14196   57      5001    0   1       0       8558
x   0       8       foo     61  na      na      na      na      1   na      na      na      na      0   15000   57      5361    na  na      na      na
x   0       8       foo     59  na      na      na      na      0   na      na      na      na      1   15000   57      6041    na  na      na      na
x   0       8       foo     54  na      na      na      na      0   na      na      na      na      3   14196   57      5841    1   1       0       7565
y   0       7       foo     61  3500    -35     -100    na      0   na      na      na      na      2   15000   57      5401    na  na      na      na
y   0       7       foo     59  na      na      na      na      1   na      na      na      na      0   15000   57      5441    na  na      na      na
y   0       7       foo     59  na      na      na      na      1   na      na      na      na      2   15000   57      5601    na  na      na      na
y   0       8       foo     61  na      na      na      na      1   na      na      na      na      4   15000   57      5401    na  na      na      na
y   0       8       foo     54  na      na      na      na      0   na      na      na      na      0   14196   57      5081    2   1       0       9507
y   0       8       foo     54  na      na      na      na      0   na      na      na      na      1   14196   57      5721    3   1       0       9547
y   0       7       foo     59  na      na      na      na      0   na      na      na      na      4   15000   57      5641    na  na      na      na
```

I want the new data table will be as below

```
key date    cat1    data1_id1-54_id2-0  data2_id1-54-id2-0  …   data8_id1-54_id2-1_id3-1_id4-0  data8_id1-61_id2-0_id3-2
x   0       7       4065                -41                     14196                           na
x   0       8                   
y   0       7       3000                -35                     na                              15000
y   0       8
```

Question : How to convert multiple row to single row of data by column name come from its row value,
currently, I'm doing by iterating row by row and create new dataframe by appending the column
but It's too slow and look like a dumb code.

Alternatively, This data was collected as an array dimension by row.

example

```
key date    id0 id1 data1 data2
x   0       0   0   10  20
x   0       0   1   20  30
x   0       1   0   40  50
x   0       1   1   60  80
```

I was query from database and concatenate in dataframe if you have any other suggestion like how to query this data to be single row it would be good also,

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`pd.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```py
df_ = df.pivot(index=['key', 'date', 'cat1', 'cat2'], columns=['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'])
df_.columns = df_.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_' + '_'.join([f'id{i}-{v}'
                                                               for i, v in enumerate(list(x)[1:])
                                                               if v != 'na']))
df_ = df_.reset_index()
```

```
print(df_)

  key  date  cat1 cat2  ... data13_id0-61_id1-1_id2-4 data13_id0-54_id1-0_id2-0_id3-2 data13_id0-54_id1-0_id2-1_id3-3 data13_id0-59_id1-0_id2-4
0   x     0     7  foo  ...                       NaN                             NaN                             NaN                       NaN
1   x     0     8  foo  ...                       NaN                             NaN                             NaN                       NaN
2   y     0     7  foo  ...                       NaN                             NaN                             NaN                        na
3   y     0     8  foo  ...                        na                            9507                            9547                       NaN

[4 rows x 214 columns]
```